# Jenkins, cygpath plugin does not convert paths

Tags: bash, jenkins, cygwin, cygpath

I'm using [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) with [Cygpath plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Cygpath+Plugin) installed.

I have some scripts that is working in Cygwin bash without problems

```
#!/bin/bash

pwd

SCRIPTFILENAME=$(readlink -f $0)
SCRIPTPATH=`dirname $SCRIPTFILENAME`
cd $SCRIPTPATH
(python check_for_clip_duplicates.py) || exit $?
```

But when i'm trying to build it with Jenkins i have en error:

```
$ D:\cygwin\bin\cygpath -w d:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
[default] $ D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -xe C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson2178008588278192726.sh
cygwin warning:
MS-DOS style path detected: C:\Windows\TEMP\hudson2178008588278192726.sh
  Preferred POSIX equivalent is: /cygdrive/c/Windows/TEMP/hudson2178008588278192726.sh
  CYGWIN environment variable option "nodosfilewarning" turns off this warning.
  Consult the user's guide for more details about POSIX paths:
http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using.html#using-pathnames
+ sh tools/generate_all.sh pc compress reset --use-texture-packer
tools/generate_all.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
tools/generate_all.sh: line 3: $'pwd\r': command not found
tools/generate_all.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
tools/generate_all.sh: line 7: cd: /cygdrive/d/Jenkins/workspace/default/tools

: No such file or directory
C:\Python27\python.exe: can't open file 'check_for_clip_duplicates.py': [Errno 2] No such     file or directory
tools/generate_all.sh: line 8: exit: 2
: numeric argument required
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

In Jenkins configuration in Shell executable i have: d:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe.

Main problem is that cygdrive paths does not work:

```
tools/generate_all.sh: line 7: cd: /cygdrive/d/Jenkins/workspace/default/tools

: No such file or directory
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some Windows line endings in your file - try running `dos2unix` on it:

```
$ dos2unix /cygdrive/c/Windows/TEMP/hudson2178008588278192726.sh
```

Then try running the script again.

Comment: problem is not with windowsline edings, problem is that paths are not converted to unix style, and tools/generate_all.sh: line 7: cd: /cygdrive/d/Jenkins/workspace/default/tools

: No such file or directory is not wroking

Comment: Is `D:\Jenkins\workspace\default\tools` an existing directory? If you try and navigate to `/cygdrive/d/Jenkins/workspace/default/tools` from the command line (starting from `/cygdrive`), how far do you get? The `'\r'` errors you get are from Windows line endings, I suspect there is one on the end of your `cd` command as well which is causing the failure.

Comment: paths are existing. I do not know from where script have '\r'. I have check this. dos2unix is not changing file content.

Comment: Try outputting the result of `dos2unix` into another file, then running that file: `dos2unix /cygdrive/c/Windows/TEMP/hudson2178008588278192726.sh > /cygdrive/c/Windows/TEMP/test.sh; chmod 755 /cygdrive/c/Windows/TEMP/test.sh; D:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe -xe /cygdrive/c/Windows/TEMP/test.sh`

Comment: i can not this is temp file generated via after finished action it's removed.

Comment: Sorry, try running `dos2unix` on the location of your script, making sure it outputs to a different location (then run that): `dos2unix D:\Jenkins\etc\generate_tools.sh > D:\Jenkins\etc\test.sh`

Comment: dos2unix does not change anything in generate_all.sh it's 100% UNIX file

Comment: If it was 100% UNIX file, it wouldn't have `\r`. The `dos2unix` suggestion is correct, though you wouldn't notice a difference with the naked eye. The problem with that suggestion is that `/cygdrive/c/Windows/TEMP/hudson2178008588278192726.sh` is a temporary file that Jenkin's *Shell Execute* step generates. You need to do that on the source, i.e. `$WORKSPACE/tools/generate_all.sh` where `$WORKSPACE` is your Job's workspace location, or in the SVN/SCM if you are checking out that file. Also, don't use Windows editors (notepad.exe, winword.exe) for modifying this file

Answer (score 0):

The script is most likely failing because your `cd $SCRIPTPATH` is failing (due to trailing `\r` characters) and it then tries to find `check_for_clip_duplicates.py` in the current directory of the script (instead of `tools` directory), which isn't there.

Why do all previous commands fail and only the last one executes? Cause the last one doesn't actually have a newline, therefore no `\r` there.

Download [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/), it's an essential tool and has great support for file EOL conversion (your problem with `\r`)

- Open **Notepad++**
- Click **File** -> **New**
- Note at the bottom right in the status bar, it will show *Dos\Windows* (default EOL)
- Click **Edit** -> **EOL Conversion** -> **UNIX Format**
- Note at the bottom right in the status bar, it will now show *UNIX*
- Please type out (don't copy paste) the content of your `generate_all.sh` script
- Save this file to your `tools/generate_all.sh` location. *You* may not notice the difference, but the line endings are invisible in normal view.
- ***Important:*** If you are using SVN or other SCM to checkout into Jenkins' workspace, you need to save your changes back to SVN/SCM!

Finally, to avoid this happening again, you can put the `dos2unix` command into your **Execute Shell** build step that you use to trigger `generate_all.sh`:

```
dos2unix toos/generate_all.sh
tools/generate_all.sh pc compress reset --use-texture-packer
```

*Pro tip:*
To actually view line endings, in Notepad++, click View -> Show Symbol -> Show All Characters

***EDIT:***
You call python from your script, which in turn calls Windows executable `C:\Python27\python.exe`. As an external executable, it has no awareness of any Jenkins plugins (cygpath) or even Jenkins itself, for that matter.

Analyzing your question further, there is little need for Cygwin in the first place, you can do all that with regular **Execute Windows Batch command** build step

`cd` is Windows equivalent of `pwd`.
`$WORKSPACE` is an environment variable pointing to the path of your job's workspace, and you *know* the script is in `tools` folder.
The `|| exit $?` can be substituted with `|| exit %ERRORLEVEL%` but it is completely redundant if this is the last line in the build step (script, actually). Jenkins will use the exit code of the last statement of the build step as the exit code for the whole build step

So change your whole cygwin build step to regular **Execute Window Batch** build step with the following:

```
cd
cd $WORKSPACE/tools
C:\Python27\python.exe check_for_clip_duplicates.py
```

If your python directory is already in the `%PATH%` variable, you can simply use `python` instead of full path.

Comment: really? please read comments. It's not problem with EOL of this file, justo jenkins is missing up this file. It's 100% unix style.

Comment: Your cygwin script does nothing other than extract `$SCRIPTPATH` and call Python `C:\Python27\python.exe` to execute `check_for_clip_duplicates.py`. Considering that your call to Python is an external call to OS executable, that executable has zero awareness of any Jenkins plugins (including cygpath). There is no reason you can't write the same in *Execute Windows Batch command* step and just pass `$WORKSPACE/tools/check_for_clip_duplicates.py`

Comment: Updated answer in relation to the above comment

Comment: this scripts must be platform independent we use this on mac / windows